# Iterate through nested JSON object array and access inner token value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am parsing a JSON object from a JSON file, a sample of the structure of which is shown below:

```
{
  "Context": [   
    {   
      "name": "Cities",
      "cities": [ "hyd", "bang", "chennai" ],
      "location": [
        {
          "city": [ "hyd" ],
          "address": "xxx"
        },
        {
          "city": [ "hyd", "bang" ],
          "address": "xxx"
        },
       
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to get the value of the token 'city' from:

```
 "location": [
        {
          "city": [ "hyd" ],
          "address": "xxx"
        },
        {
          "city": [ "hyd", "bang" ],
          "address": "xxx"
        }
      ]
```

Using the below code, I am able to get the value of the token "name":

```
StreamReader rs = new StreamReader("Jsonfilepath\.json");

string json = rs.ReadToEnd();
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json).Children();

List<JToken> tokens = jsonObject.Children().Children().ToList();

var value = tokens.Any(each =>each["name"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("cities"));
```

How can I get the value of the token "city" instead?

Comment: Why not deserialize the entire object into a model and after that, select the property that you want with a simple Linq query?

Comment: Do you want to get all `city` values that are in location .

Comment: i cannot use model here , need to send Dynamic json  response to UI from API. i am passing city as input parameter to API (ex : "Hyd")

Comment: i want all city values in if condition check ,  need to modify JSON object using city value

Comment: Does you json is a part of json or its a full json. If its part of json then please show full json

Comment: i posted part of json , it's context array only. help me with piece of code to  get city values

Comment: With this "jsonObject.Children().Children()" you are handling only 2 levels of depth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can querying json to get your desired result like

```
JToken jToken = JToken.Parse(json);

var result = jToken["Context"].SelectMany(x => x["location"].SelectMany(y => y["city"].Select(z => z)).ToList());

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

## Online Demo

You can get distinct value by using below code

```
result = result.Distinct();
```

**Further Reading:**

- [Querying Json with Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJson.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the precise question of accessing the city value, you have to change your `any` to a `FirstOrDefault`

```
 var value = tokens.FirstOrDefault(each=>each["name"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("cities"));
 if (value != null)
     var city = value["city"];
```

This will give you the json node instead of telling you whether is exist or not (if it does not exist it will be null).

You can probably simplify everything using SelectToken :

```
var cities = jsonObject.SelectToken("$.Context[?(@.name == 'Cities')].location.city");
```

I did not try last query but this give you a hint on how you might try to improve your json management.

More doc here: [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm)